# GAP — null multidimensional array

Tags: gap

I need to create an $n\times a \times b$ array in GAP. How do I do that fast?

I tried putting

```
e := NullMat(a,b);
Array := [];
for i in [1..n] do
Array[i] := e;
od;
```

However, then when I try to change a single entry, GAP changes it in every copy of $e$. And this is far from ideal.

Comment: If there is another way of initialising a multidimensional array, I'll be really happy too.

Comment: The reason my version isn't working may be due to NullMat being mutable.

Comment: In related programming languages such as javascript, objects are technically pointers to memory.  Modifying one modifies the memory to which it is pointing, causing all other variables who point to the same memory to be affected as well.  Surely there should be a "new" keyword so that you can initialize new memory rather than reuse the same pointer each time.  Something like changing the line from `Array[i] := e` to `Array[i] := new NullMat(a,b)` because setting it to `e` each time is just pointing it to the same memory location each and every time.

Comment: See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050004/modifying-a-copy-of-a-javascript-object-is-causing-the-original-object-to-change) explaining the phenomenon in javascript quite well.

Comment: Indeed, what @JMoravitz writes is what happens. `e` is a pointer to the same object. You could use `StructuralCopy(e)` to get an equal, but disjoint object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! The following construction works alright. However, I don't know how to do that in an arbitrary dimension.

```
Array := [];
for i in [1..n] do
    Array[i] := NullMat(a,b);
od;
```